# Find x from the given relation

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

If $$\sin^{-1}\Big(x-\frac{x^2}{2} +\frac{x^4}{4} ...\infty \Big)+\cos^{-1}\Big(x^2 -\frac{x^4}{2} +\frac{x^6}{4} ...\infty \Big) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ where $0<|x|<1.414$ then $x$ equals:

Now I tried to use $\sin^{-1}(x) + \cos^{-1}(x) =\frac{\pi}{2}$ and thus equated the equations inside the inverse trigonometric functions in the questions. But neither am I getting anything from this nor could I find any other method. Please help. Cheers!!

Comment: Actually its not very clear what $...$ stands for, what are the actual sequences?

Comment: Both arguments have to be equal

Comment: may be you mean Let $$S=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{4}+\cdots \cdots \infty=\frac{x}{1+x/2}$$

Comment: @Sri , Are you sure there is no typo and the denominator of $x^6$ in $\ cos^{-1}$ is not $3$ ? Could you write some more terms?

Comment: What is the general term of both series? I don't see a pattern from $3$ terms

Comment: The answer to all your questions is that this is what is given. There is no typo or anything. Thanks guys. Please let me know if you got the answer.

Comment: @jacky could you please explain how you did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for the equation $\sin^{-1}(a)+\cos^{-1}(b) = \pi/2$, we can take the sin of both sides, coupled with the identity $\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$ to find that $$a - a^2 + b - b^2 = -1$$.  If you can find closed-form expressions for a and b for your problem, similar to Jacky's comment, you could try solving it this way.

Comment: Won't it be like $a+b+\sqrt{1-a^2} + \sqrt{1-b^2}=1$  ??

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake.

Comment: Can you explain how Jacky got it. I don't quiet follow it!!??

Comment: You can use the known power series $1+y+y^2+y^3+\dots = \frac{1}{1-y}$ and substitute $y = -x/2$.  Finally, multiply the series by $x$.